# Custom the Image in CoverFlow

Tags: android, xml, image, imageview, coverflow

Now I am using this coverflow: https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

I've already run the code well, but I need to my project look a little cool like this:

[image]

This red line is something like:

[image]

And I want to add the image inside this shape. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    FancyCoverFlow fancyCoverFlow;
    ImageView imageView;
    RelativeLayout backgroundLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fancyCoverFlow = (FancyCoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.fancyCoverFlow);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        backgroundLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.backgroundlayout);

        final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
        fancyCoverFlow.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        fancyCoverFlow.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                backgroundLayout.setBackgroundResource(myAdapter.getItem(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow;
import at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlowAdapter;

public class MyAdapter extends FancyCoverFlowAdapter {
    private int[] images = {R.drawable.rain,R.drawable.rain2,R.drawable.rain_forest,
            R.drawable.rain,R.drawable.rain2,R.drawable.rain_forest};
    private String[] nameImage = {"Rain1", "Rain2", "Rain3", "Rain4", "Rain5", "Rain6"};
    private Context mContext;


    public MyAdapter(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer getItem(int i) {
        return images[i];
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }


    @Override
    public View getCoverFlowItem(int i, View reuseableView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        reuseableView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, viewGroup, false);
        RelativeLayout rlMain =(RelativeLayout) reuseableView.findViewById(R.id.rlMain);
        rlMain.setLayoutParams(new FancyCoverFlow.LayoutParams(400,400));
        TextView txtName = (TextView) reuseableView.findViewById(R.id.txtNameimage);
        ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) reuseableView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        txtName.setText(nameImage[i]);
        ivImage.setImageResource(images[i]);
        return reuseableView;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fcf="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/rain_forest"
    android:id="@+id/backgroundlayout">

    <at.technikum.mti.fancycoverflow.FancyCoverFlow
        android:id="@+id/fancyCoverFlow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        fcf:maxRotation="80"
        fcf:unselectedAlpha="0.3"
        fcf:unselectedSaturation="0.0"
        fcf:unselectedScale="0.4"
        fcf:scaleDownGravity="0.5"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and custom_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNameimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Tên ảnh"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to add that water drop behind your coverflow to all of your pictures?

Comment: You can put it behind your coverflow in xml, but it will be static and won't be moved with the other pictures. If you want to add it to each one of your pictures separately, the easiest way to do that is by using photoshop. Put the water drop as the first layer and the rain background as the second layer.

Comment: When the item of fancycoverflow selected, the background behind will change, does your way work with it? You mean put the drop water in ImageView src in custom_layout.xml?

Comment: I think yes, did you try it? Tell me if it does or not.

Comment: I've already add the circle in src of ImageView in custom_layout.xml, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Make sure that your waterdrop image is larger than the rain imageview. Play with layout width and height.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91469/discussion-between-hussein-el-feky-and-khuong291).

Comment: Please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996878/showing-gif-image-with-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already solved this by using Photoshop. I think using photoshop for this case is simpler than other ways.