# Showing Gif Image with Library

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif

I am using this library to show gif image: https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView

But I don't know how to implement my gif image in these code. I have some GifImages in assets folder.

Here is my code:

PlayActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class PlayActivity extends Activity{

    GifImageView gifView;
    //byte[] bytes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_play_activity);

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("rain_4.gif");
            byte[] bytes = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(bytes);
            is.close();

            gifView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);
            gifView = new GifImageView(this);
            gifView.setBytes(bytes);
            gifView.startAnimation();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(gifView != null) gifView.startAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(gifView != null) gifView.startAnimation();
    }
}
```

And layout_play_activity.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PlayActivity">

    <com.felipecsl.gifimageview.library.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library link you provided had a sample within it. Your way of loading the GifImageView was different from the way written in the sample. The sample was downloading a gif from the internet.

**Here is a snippet from MainActivity of the sample:**

```
GifImageView gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);

new GifDataDownloader() {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final byte[] bytes) {
        gifImageView.setBytes(bytes);
        gifImageView.startAnimation();
        Log.d(TAG, "GIF width is " + gifImageView.getGifWidth());
        Log.d(TAG, "GIF height is " + gifImageView.getGifHeight());
    }
}.execute("http://gifs.joelglovier.com/aha/aha.gif");
```

## Solution:

I am not sure if you can load GifImageView from your assets with this library, but I prefer using ion library. It's really nice and simple. With that library, you can also stretch gif images as you like:

https://github.com/koush/ion

**Simple Example:**

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Ion.with(imageView).load("http://gifs.joelglovier.com/aha/aha.gif");
```

Comment: I don't know how to start a chat room, can you start it? Also did you try the method mentioned in the video?

Comment: Gif Image only show 1/4 size at the top-left of the screen.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that unfortunately you can not change the size of the gif if you use this method, but still you can change its place on screen. However, maybe you will need to use a library called ion library. It's very famous for displaying gif images. Google it please. :)

Comment: Can this library help the Gif Image show full screen?

Comment: I am not sure if it can stretch images or not, but as far as I know, it is the most library used to show gif images. However, if you really want to stretch a gif image, You should decompile the gif image from any website online and create an animation drawable file with those images. This is the most efficient way to do it as Android Developers themselves still didn't add support to show gif images. Animation Drawable was thus made for that.

Comment: I will update my answer if you feel that Animation Drawable is suitable for you. Just tell me. :)

Comment: The Ion library is awesome. Finally, everything work nice now :), thank you :)

Comment: Sure, I'll try to help. Would you also mind marking my answer as correct if it solved your issue? Thanks. :)

Comment: please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262316/how-to-create-a-simple-game-with-multiplayer-via-bluetooth

Answer (score 2):

1.I would suggest you to checkout **Image Management Library by Facebook** that is [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) that is pretty awesome and mature as compared to other Image Loading Library.

2.Fresco has `SimpleDraweeView` as custom image view which supports `Rounded Corners and Circles` [link](http://frescolib.org/docs/rounded-corners-and-circles.html#_) and **supports Animated(.gif, .webp) as well as Normal Images(.jpg, .png).**

3.Fresco handles all the things caching of images with 3 Tier architecture ( `BITMAP_MEMORY_CACHE`, `ENCODED_MEMORY_CACHE` and `DISK_CACHE`). It also reduces OOM(Out Of Memory) issues. When image in a view goes out of screen it automatically recycles the bitmap, hence releasing the memory.

Comment: I usually advise against Fresco because it requires a complete overhaul of a project to properly implement. For most projects, Glide is more than adequate.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to put you gif in the assets folder. The assets folder is not created by default in Android Studio projects, so you should create a directory in `src/main/assets` and put your .gif files inside. *The drawable resources folder should be reserved for drawables.*

You can use an input stream to load the bytes into your byte array, this is done inside your `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_play_activity);
    try {
        //animation.gif is just an example, use the name of your file
        //that is inside the assets folder.

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("animation.gif");
        bytes = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(bytes);
        is.close();

        gifView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);
        gifView = new GifImageView(this);
        gifView.setBytes(bytes);
        gifView.startAnimation();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already do this (try/catch with those), but it shows error: java.lang.NullPointerException, error with this line: bytes = new byte[is.available()];

Comment: can you post your stack trace?

Comment: I'm on my mobile, so I'd prefer that you update your question

Comment: that's wrong on so many levels... :\ I will update my answer with something you can copy and paste, but you really should go back to your java basics before attempting to write an android app. give me a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), since it does animated GIFs without any modifications, and can fit into any project.

It also has the added benefit of smoother loading and proper resizing, if you're using these images in any type of recycled view.

---

As @fixmycode said, you are never defining bytes[], if you want to use your current implementation.